# How to refresh a page other than the current one in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, page-refresh

I would like to update a page other than the one in which the user presses the button, I know that to update the page itself just use the

`setState (() {})`

but what I want to do is update the HomePage when the user presses a button that is on the main.dart page. How can I solve?

What I thought and that it works but badly is to use the

`Navigator.push (context, MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) => const MyApp ()));`

when the user presses the button, and doing so it works because it updates my MyApp (main.dart), the problem is that when they press the button in this way you see the same animation as when you open the app and it is very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function with setState in it to the other page and run the function after click the buttton

something like this:

```
class Startpage extends StatefulWidget {


const Startpage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Startpage> createState() => StartpageState();
}

class StartpageState extends State<Startpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>  SecondPage(updateStartPage: () {
                        setState(() {
                          //add your logic
                        });
                      })),
            ),
        child: const Text("navigate to second page"));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function updateStartPage;
  const SecondPage({super.key, required this.updateStartPage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => updateStartPage(),
      child: const Text("update parent"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I start thanking you for your help, I created a void in main.dart, but how can I pass it to the homepage and where should I insert it?

Comment: Thanks again, I have another problem but, my HomePage and MyApp are the two different .dart files and I don't know how to transfer the Function from one to the other, is there a way to do it or am I forced to put them in the same file?

Comment: no u are not forced to put them in the same file, u can use provider package it's a better solution here is the link to the package: https://pub.dev/packages/provider